# Elasticsearch - how to filter/query for a parameter value?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, parameters

I'm new to Elasticsearch and I have the following question about parameter comparison at filter/query:

- In SQL I have something like the code below, where I compare a SQL value with a parameter value and the parameter value with a fixed value

  WHERE (customer.id = :customer_id OR :customer_id = '111')
- The left part of the OR above is ok, but how I compare the right part?

  { "bool": {
      "should": [
          { "term": 
              { "customer.id": "@customer_id" } 
          }, 
          { 
              ???? 
          }
      ]
  }}

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

The mapping:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "store" : true,
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
    },
    "_timestamp" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "store" : true
    },
    "properties" : {
        ...
        "processDefinition.id" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "doc_values" : true
        },
        "processDefinition.key" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "doc_values" : true
        },
        "processDefinition.name" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "variables" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
                ...
                "executionId" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed",
                    "doc_values" : true
                },
                "id" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed",
                    "doc_values" : true
                },
                "name" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed",
                    "doc_values" : true
                },
                "originalType" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed",
                    "doc_values" : true
                },
                "rawValue" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed",
                    "doc_values" : true
                },
                "storedType" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed",
                    "doc_values" : true
                },
                "stringValue" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want every "variables.rawValue": "@parameter" OR "@parameter": "ABC". Keep in mind that if @parameter is equals to "a", then the filter returns only info related to "a". If @parameter is equals to "ABC", then the filter returns info related to everything, because company ABC is owner of everything sub company (like "a). I can have a user from "a" using the filter or a user from "ABC".

I tried this:

```
"bool": {
    "should": {
         "terms": {
            "variables.rawValue": [
                   "@currentUser_company", 
                   "ABC"
            ]
         }
     }
 }
```

But the filter join the result from "a" with "ABC".

One last thing. The ES version is 1.7.

Comment: How will specify value using `@customer_id`. That does not work in elasticsearch I guess.

Comment: 'customer_id' is a value that is specified when the user fill a form and is passed using javascript. 'customer_id' maybe is not the best example, but it also could be a date or a string value... All queries/filters here are process using Rythm Engine which uses @param_name as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "should": [
        {
            "terms": {
               "FIELD": [
                  "@customer_id",
                  "111"
               ]
            }
        }
     ]
   }
 }
}
```

`@customer_id` is the value which user passes

Comment: I tried but the result is wrong. Another example: we have Company AA and its 3 sub companies (a, b, and c). The WHERE clause (user.company = :user_company OR :user_company = 'AA') where :user_id is the company of the current user. If user is from sub-company 'b', then the query just return 'b' info. If user is from company 'A', then the query return info about everything (AA, a, b, and c).

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: I got everything from 'AA' (with 'b' inside)... but the user from company 'b' can not see info pro 'AA', 'a' or 'c'. In your example, 'b' is seeing everything. Only the user from company AA could see everything.

Comment: `index` structure is not clear. `Mapping` is also not mentioned in your question. Please specify all these details.